# How to integrate AngularJS view with Wordpress?

Tags: angularjs, wordpress

I'm doing some testing with AngularJS and WordPress but I can't seem to figure out how to get ng-view to work with WP. My knowledge about WP/php is extremely limited and I should probably do more tutorials on those before trying to do what I'm trying to do (I'm planning to do that after I solve this problem).

There are no folders in my theme. Here is my code:

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> ng-app="myTestApp">
    <head>
        <title>My Test Theme</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>header</p>
```

index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div ng-controller="homeController">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#my_page">My page</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

footer.php

```
<p>footer</p>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>        
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
    var myTestApp = angular.module('myTestApp', ['ngRoute']);

myTestApp.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('home', {
      templateUrl: 'home.php',
      controller: 'homeController'
    })
    .when('my_page', {
      templateUrl: 'my_page.php',
      controller: 'koncertyController'
    });
});

myTestApp.controller('homeController', function($scope){
});

myTestApp.controller('my_pageController', function($scope){
});
```

functions.php

```
    <?php 
function my_test_theme_enqueue_scripts() {
  // enqueue jQuery and AngularJS
  wp_register_script('angular-core', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.js', array(), null, false);
  wp_enqueue_script('angular-route', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular-route.min.js', array('angular-core'), null, false);
  wp_register_script('angular-app', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/app.js', array('angular-core'), null, false);

  // enqueue all scripts
  wp_enqueue_script('angular-core');
  wp_enqueue_script('angular-route');
  wp_enqueue_script('angular-app');
  wp_enqueue_script('angular-directives');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_test_theme_enqueue_scripts');
?>
```

I believe the problem lies in functions.php. Thanks!

Comment: What errors are in the console?

Answer (score -1):

I believed your problem relies on the php files since php files generate html on the server side. Since Angularjs is a client-side framework you can't get that working for you.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Just clarifying that there is nothing in php preventing you from integrating Angular to a page generated using php. Apologies I've no experience of WP