# How to connect AngularJS with WordPress?

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, http

I have a mobile app that I am constructing with Ionic Framework, I've been researching trough the web trying to get any tutorial which give me the answer to my question: how can I connect my app with WordPress?

all I see is questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703995/how-to-integrate-angularjs-view-with-wordpress)

I don't want/need to touch anything in the WordPress part, unless I need any plugin or something, all I need is to display the posts of WordPress account in my mobile app main view, so, is there any tutorial you can show me which goes straight to the point? do you have any example?

My app is running with Angular, so I need to do everything with it.

I saw [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCnGSOaaZFo) but he is doing it with something named Freshly-Pressed, how can I do it but with my own WP ?

Comment: Angular wants JSON would suggest you use something like this https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/ or roll your own server side code that accesses the WP DB directly and allows you to use JSON as the format for request/response data for angular or any other data consumer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find any tutorial but you can acheive this with [WP-REST API](http://wp-api.org/). Which gives you to fetch posts or create posts and more.

OR If you want to acheive it through a plugin then follow this post http://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-json-rest-api/